# Adding a dictionary inside a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like this:

```
store = {}
```

And I have a bunch of data in another dictionary that looks like this:

```
items = {"hardware_items":23, "fruit_items":5, "fish_items": 23}
```

How can I put the items dictionary inside the store dict so I can achieve the following result?

```
store = {"hardware_items":23, "fruit_items":5, "fish_items": 23}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method:

```
store.update(items)
```

This will add everything in `items` to `store`; beware though that if `store` already has existing keys with those names they will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

If store dict is empty you can use the `copy()` method :

```py
store = items.copy()
```

You can use `store = items` but it works as a reference (then modifying store will modify items)

Else, you can use a for loop :

```py
for keys in items:
    store[keys] = items[keys]
```

It will overwrite value if a key is already declared.

Answer (score 0):

The output you want would appear to be a copy of the "items" dictionary in "store". You can do this, basically, in two ways.

### 1. Simple copy

You can write

```
store = items
```

and the output will be what you asked for.
Changing one of the two dictionaries, however, will also change the other.

### 2. Deep Copy

One of the ways to do a deep copy is:

```
store=copy.deepcopy(items)
```

In this case you will have two dictionaries with the same content, but they will be independent and you can edit them separately. Let me show an example:

```
import copy

store = {}
items = {"hardware_items":23, "fruit_items":5, "fish_items": 23}

#Print
print("Before operations")
print("ITEMS> "+str(items))
print("STORE> "+str(store))

store=copy.deepcopy(items)

#Print
print("After deep copy")
print("ITEMS> "+str(items))
print("STORE> "+str(store))


items["hardware_items"]=3

#Print
print("let's modify the first key value")
print("ITEMS> "+str(items))
print("STORE> "+str(store))
```

Your output will be:

[image: image example]