# Adding a dictionary inside a dictionary for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like this:

```
dict1 = {'Store_1': {},
 'Store_2': {}}
```

And I have a list of dictionaries which I would like to put into store1 and store 2.

```
[{'Apple': '726',
  'Pear': '777',
  'Orange': '1.004',
  'Pineapple': '696',
  'melon': '828'},

 {'orange': '650',
  'melon': '654',
  'avocado': '657',
  'pear': '645',
  'apple': '647',
  'berries': '655'}]
```

The desired output would be:

```
dict1 = {'Store_1': {'Apple': '726', 'Pear': '777', 'Orange': '1.004', ...}, 'Store_2': {'orange': '650', 'melon': '654', ...}}
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: It depends on what criterion you're using to put those dicts into `dict1`. Dicts don't necessarily have order, so are you trying to add them so that `'Store_1'` corresponds to the first item in the list, `'Store_2'` corresponds to the second item in the list, and so on?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: And do you only have `'Store_1'` and `'Store_2'`, or do you also want to support `'Store_3'`, etc.?

Comment: How does your problem differ from your [previous problem: Adding a dictionary inside a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64012765/adding-a-dictionary-inside-a-dictionary)? What trouble do you have applying the previous answers?

Comment: Kyle, yep I would like to support Store_3 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l=[{'Apple': '726',
  'Pear': '777',
  'Orange': '1.004',
  'Pineapple': '696',
  'melon': '828'},
 {'orange': '650',
  'melon': '654',
  'avocado': '657',
  'pear': '645',
  'apple': '647',
  'berries': '655'}]
Dict1={}
for x in range(len(l)):
    Dict1['Store_{}'.format(x+1)]=l[x]
print(Dict1)
    

>>> {'Store_1': {'Apple': '726', 'Pear': '777', 'Orange': '1.004', 'Pineapple': '696', 'melon': '828'}, 'Store_2': {'orange': '650', 'melon': '654', 'avocado': '657', 'pear': '645', 'apple': '647', 'berries': '655'}}
```

The way this works is by looping through the length of the list, and for each iteration first taking the value in the list, then creating a key in the dictionary (using`.format`)with the name of that number.

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: Note that the numbering in the question starts at 1, not 0.